# Need to write online circuit builder: please compare/contrast YUI3, GWT, and jQuery... what would YOU use?

Tags: jquery-ui, gwt, yui

I need to write a sophisticated website that does AJax, drag and drop, component re-sizing, with a tree view of all components.

If this is controversial, please just close it, but could someone please recommend a good JavaScript Application Framework to use?

I know YUI3 is still under development so I'd have to use the tree view from YUI2.

I'm torn because it appears that YUI3 looks up and coming, jQuery is most popular, and GWT looks to be the fastest... and afterall, Google uses it for some amazing things.

Any input?

Comment: Possibly a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs If you could narrow down your requirements, we could maybe help. Or at least write if you have more experience (or prefer, or don't care) in Java or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a very visual interface, [WireIt](http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/) might be of interest. It is YUI 2 based.

Answer (score 0):

Pete --

I'm a member of the YUI team, so my advice would be impartial on this -- I do think YUI 3 has [unique strengths](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=miraglia-yuiconf2009-yui3) that are worth considering.

I wanted to point out, though, that there is [a port of YUI TreeView for YUI 3 in the Gallery](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/02/18/gallery-treeview-port/).  That might be a good way to build on YUI 3's strengths while still falling back to the TreeView behavior from the 2.x codeline.

-Eric